# Jmeter- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

jp@gc-JSON Path assertion is failing in Jmeter-3. Same is working fine in Jmeter-2.13. Following is complete error trace

```
Thread started: setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/07/17 21:46:43 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: E:\jmeter3\JmxFiles\JbpmTables.csv 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished:  setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All Setup Threads have ended 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Loan ProcessGroups 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Loan ProcessGroups. 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Loan ProcessGroups 1-1 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored:  E:\Jmeter\LoanProcessGroups.csv 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = 478T5Z1 
2016/07/17 21:46:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0 
2016/07/17 21:46:50 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error processing Assertion  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonReader
at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathassertion.JSONPathAssertion.doAssert(JSONPathAssertion.java:80)
at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathassertion.JSONPathAssertion.getResult(JSONPathAssertion.java:132)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processAssertion(JMeterThread.java:755)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.checkAssertions(JMeterThread.java:746)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have [Extras with Libs set of JMeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/) installed along with JMeter 2.13 and don't have them installed for JMeter 3.0

Solutions are:

1. Switch to [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) and [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) combination
2. Install `JSON Plugin` via [JMeter Plugin Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)